# Translate java widget to kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, widget, translate

Can anybody help me with translating from java to kotlin?
I'm trying to make android widget that basically updates itself when the button is pushed.

```
public class NewAppWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {

            Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, NewAppWidget.class);
            intent1.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
            intent1.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0, intent1, 0);

            RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.new_app_widget);
            remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.buttonId, pendingIntent1);

            //there will come my action

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews);
        }
    }

}
```

Can anybody translate this for me?

Comment: You have misunderstood how Stackoverflow works, we are not code conversion service. Kindly spend sometime in Help Center and read few questions here to know how to ask good question. You need to make an attempt and ask specific question.

Comment: Yes. I understand. I know how stack works but I was doing research about this for like a week now and i couldn’t find anything in kotlin. So I asked if anybody can help me or send me some links. I am sorry.

Comment: I actually just translated your code to kotlin, I don't know how you didn't find it, check [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/converting-a-java-file-to-kotlin-file.html) page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Studio can actually convert Java to Kotlin for you. Press Code > Convert Java File to Kotlin File.